# Dataframe fill column with previous value until condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row, ffill

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| Step | Text | Parameter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | print | 1 |
| 16 | control | 2 |
| 17 | printout | 3 |
| 18 | print2 | 1 |
| 19 | Nan | 2 |
| 20 | Nan | 3 |
| 21 | Nan | 4 |
| 22 | Nan | 1 |
| 23 | Nan | 2 |
| 24 | Nan | 1 |

And I want my dataframe to look like this:

| Step | Text | Parameter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | print | 1 |
| 15 | print | 2 |
| 15 | print | 3 |
| 16 | control | 1 |
| 16 | control | 2 |
| 17 | control | 3 |
| 17 | control | 4 |
| 18 | printout | 1 |
| 18 | printout | 2 |
| 19 | print2 | 1 |

So basically when I have "1" in Parameter column, I need the next value from Step and Text.
Any ideas?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `repeat` on a custom group:

```
# ensure NaN
df['Text'] = df['Text'].replace('Nan', pd.NA)

# get the number of rows per group starting with 1
n = df.groupby(df['Parameter'].eq(1).cumsum()).size()

# repeat the index of the non NaN values as many times
idx = df['Text'].dropna().index.repeat(n)

# replace the values ignoring the index
# (using the underlying numpy array)
df[['Step', 'Text']] = df.loc[idx, ['Step', 'Text']].to_numpy()
```

output:

```
  Step      Text  Parameter
0   15     print          1
1   15     print          2
2   15     print          3
3   16   control          1
4   16   control          2
5   16   control          3
6   16   control          4
7   17  printout          1
8   17  printout          2
9   18    print2          1
```